# Unable to Work out Angle on Circle Theorem Question

Tags: geometry

[image]

Struggling with part (a) of this question. I have actually worked out part(b) before part(a) as follows: $\angle DBC = 101 = (180 - 79 - 90)$. Therefore, $\angle BDE = 180 - (101 + 42) = 38$. This means, $\angle BOE = 38 * 2 = 76$.

I have no idea about part(a) though. Can't find a way into working that out.

Comment: So are you trying to find part a) without using your result in part b)?

Comment: @ArsenBerk yes that's how the exam question should be done I expect

Comment: Write down everything you know from the diagram. For example, $\angle EBC + \angle DBE + 79 = 180$. $\angle BEC + 41 + \angle EBC = 180$. $\angle BDC + \angle DBC + 41 = 180$. $\angle ABD + \angle DBC = 180$. *Etc.* And surely if you figured out $\angle BDE$ then you have everything you know to figure out $\angle BED$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** What you are looking for is "Tangent-Chord Theorem". You can see the theorem and its proof [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/alternate-segment-theorem-2/).

Comment: OK, so I have: BDE = 38 as calculated above in my post. Therefore according to the Tangent-Chord theorem, EBC = 38. This means BEC = 101 and so BED = 79 which is the correct answer. Is that the right line of thinking?

Comment: That's also correct but you can also use the theorem for $\angle ABD$ and $\angle BED$. Then, you don't even have to use an additional information to find $\angle BED$.

Comment: Is that using the tangent-chord theorem as I thought in my reasoning I was using that theorem?

Comment: It is correct but why would you use it that way while there is a much shorter way?

Answer (score 0):

$m\angle BED = \dfrac 12m\overset{\frown}{BD} = m\angle ABD = 79^\circ$

[Tangent-chord theorem](https://www.mathwarehouse.com/geometry/circle/angle-tangent-and-chord.php)